# Are printers and their hardware problems (NOT a driver issue), on topic for Super User?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I didn't think that [this question](https://superuser.com/q/318191/81403) was on topic under Super User. I didn't flag it because printers are sort-of computer related, but... if it's only hardware?

Answer (score 5):

I'm inclined to say this is on topic.

Printers (with some exceptions) can only function correctly when attached to (or driven over a network by, etc, etc) a computer, and that should mean that printers are generally acceptable.

And while this specific question is most probably related wholly to the maintenance/repair of the printer, there is still a small chance that the problem is being caused by the driving computer.

---

But this is a bit borderline, so would be interested in seeing what everyone else thinks.

Comment: I agree that this one is very borderline. I'd leave it open for now though.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is on topic.

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/318092/can-i-use-my-computer-mouse-on-a-wet-surface) question, and its just about the mouse... I happen to think that computer hardware includes "accessories" that help a computer fulfill a function.

In addition to printers, there have been questions about KVM switches, monitors, mice joysticks, and loads of other other pieces of hardware that is not directly considered part of a standard computer. Across the board, these types to question seem to be open.

So for consistency, and because there is not reason to change it (I don't see it as a stretch to call it computer hardware), it's on topic.

Comment: I agree.  I would argue that a printer is computer hardware, since that's just about the only thing in the world that can be interfaced to it.

Comment: Well in many cases USB's can also...

Comment: STRONGLY DISAGREE!  I think there should be an accessory forum.  Computer problems, computer experts can handle.  questions on if a particular mouse can work on a wet surface isn't a computer problem or issue.  A question about compatibility is 100% valid however (I think)