# Question about printer interpretation of colors

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question about my Super User post: [Printer colors differ between ps/pdf draw commands and images](https://superuser.com/questions/1262567/printer-colors-differ-between-ps-pdf-draw-commands-and-images)

Burgi raised the concern that the linked question might be a better fit for [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). My rationale for posting here was that questions on GD about colors and document preparation focus mostly on authoring software and generation of files to print, while this question is about how printers interpret the files (what I would consider a hardware/driver issue).

Somewhat related:

- [Are questions about interfacing with printers on topic?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/11941/are-questions-about-interfacing-with-printers-on-topic)
- [Are printers and their hardware problems (NOT a driver issue), on topic for Super User?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3032/are-printers-and-their-hardware-problems-not-a-driver-issue-on-topic-for-supe)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is on topic because it has to do with computer software and hardware. That said, I do think the issue is specialized enough that you may have trouble getting an answer from this community.

It appears that your question would also be on-topic at Graphic Design. When a question is on-topic here and another site, there's nothing this community will do to compel you to move it. That's up to you. However, the Stack Exchange network as a whole does ask that you do not cross-post your question.

I suggest you give your question a chance here, then if you don't get any answers, vote to close it explaining that you're going to post it at Graphic Design, then do so once it's closed.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll do that.